# Less Windows Node.js Hanging

Tags: windows, node.js, symfony, less, assetic

I have been trying to setup Symfony2 on Windows so that I can use assetic with less.

I have installed node.js for Windows (0.6.8). Then I have run `npm install less --global` and found less in `C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

As far as my Symfony setup, I have the master branch of `Assetic` (due to a bug I read about in 1.0.2), but the standard v1.0.1 of `AsseticBundle`

After some work, I was able to get an example less file to render via:
    http://localhost/app_dev.php/css/compiled-main_part_1_boilerplate_1.css

Then I switched a .less file that @imports other .less files (in the same subdirectory).  Whenever I try to go to that page on my local server (using this less configuration) it hangs and I can see a command process and a node.exe process both running.

The command is trying to run a script in node.js which exists in my temporary directory.  I can run that file through node.js in a command prompt fine, but I cannot get it to load using Symfony/Assetic.

Is there anyway to use node.js, less, and assetic on Windows?

Here is my relevant config file sections:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:           %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles: [FeedStreamMainBundle]
    # java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less:
            node: %assetic_node%
            node_paths: [%assetic_less_path%]
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar
        # closure:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/compiler.jar
```

dev config override:

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

in parameters.ini:

```
assetic_node="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node"
assetic_less_path="C:\\Users\\Matt\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules"
```

Comment: I changed the parameters to this: `assetic_less_path="C:\\web_workspace\\lib\\node_modules"` and I can get the page http://localhost/app_dev.php/css/compiled-main_part_1_boilerplate_1.css to load once again.  Then I try to load that page again or a normal page and it just hangs again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one really has any answers, I can only assume there are very few Windows developers using LESS and node.js in Symfony2.

My solution was to use lessphp which worked fine once I got it into the autoloader.

Comment: I haven't looked into this in a year. But probably not. Open an issue on it maybe?

Comment: I opened one here https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/155 if you can, vote it

Comment: There's a bug in Assetic. I have opened a pull request to fix it https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/pull/411 . The reason was that the env variable *SystemRoot* has not been passed to the node.js process.

Answer (score 4):

yes, use [lessphp](https://gist.github.com/3082684) (server side)

> ### Symfony2.1. How to integrate assetic lessphp filter. Add the following
>
> #### package to your composer.json:
>
> ```
> "require": {
>     ...
>     "leafo/lessphp": "dev-master",
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> #### Run php composer.phar update
>
> #### and update your config.yml
>
> ```
> #...
> assetic:
>     #...
>     filters:
>         lessphp:
>             file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
>             apply_to: "\.less$"
> ```

or use the [less.js](http://lesscss.org) (client side)

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the following and this works for me. NOTE that it is 'node.exe' and not just node.

```
node: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe"
node_paths: ["C:\\Users\\Ben\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules"] 
apply_to:   "\.less$"
```

Comment: Since there is a bug in new implementation of less in lessphp, this solution worked