# Runtime exception when trying to dump assetic for Symfony2 project using Windows 7

Tags: windows, symfony, coffeescript, sass, assetic

I am using Windows platform (please do not laugh at me). And I am trying to build a Symfony2 project using asseti in my localmachine that is running Windows 7.

Now I can not for the love of my life figure out why it is not dumping the assetic files. It is always saying some kind of RunTime Exception. I think it has to do with the coffee bin and node path. Is this the right way to set paths for coffee bin and node?

```
framework:
    [...]


# Twig Configuration
twig:
    [...]

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: true
    bundles: [...]


    filters:
        sass:
            load_paths: [ "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/xxxxx/WebsiteBundle/Resources/public/vendor/" ]
            compass: true
        coffee:
            bin: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\coffee
            node: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node
        cssrewrite: ~


# Doctrine Configuration
[...]
```

`php composer.phar` install works fine

`php app/console asset:install` works fine

`php app/console assetic:dump` gives me the following error:

> [RuntimeException]
>
> Unable to write file C:/xampp/htdocs/xxxxx/app/../web/js/3b27a3f_js?key=AIzaSyCk9Cxgv09X9DKar1bcsLAXxlqP3YhF0OI_1.js

My initial feeling is that something wrong with the coffee bin and node path.

Below is where those are in my machine.

[image]

[image]

I have no idea what's going on. I'll dump you any output that might help solve this. I feel clueless here. I am using SASS, Compass, coffee, etc.

Comment: I think my colleague had the similar issue recently, try to run `cmd` as administrator (I don't have windows)

Comment: I have been running these as administrator in windows. No effect.

Comment: Can you please copy paste the error message to replace the image? The error comes when Symfony2 tries to create the `.../3b27a3f_js?key=AIzaSyC...` file, that's not a valid filename.

Comment: Add -v option (--verbose) to the dump command. It will show stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**integration of Symfony2 and Assetic**

**1.** file config.yml

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
    less: 
        node: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe"
        node_paths: ["C:\\Users\\websky\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules"] 
        apply_to:   "\.less$"
    yui_css: 
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/../java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar 
    yui_js: 
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/../java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar 
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
```

**2.** file base.html.twig

```
    <head> 
        {% stylesheets filter='less,?yui_css' '@AcmeBundle/Resources/less/main.less' %} 
        <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" /> 
        {% endstylesheets %} 
    </head>
```

**3.** building assetic

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

**useful link:**
[Less Windows Node.js Hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029821/less-windows-node-js-hanging)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
coffee:
   bin: "C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\coffee"
   node: "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node"
```

I had exactly the same problem with node.  If this doesnt work, try pointing to the exact .exe path.  Windows seems to have all sorts of trouble.

Good luck

Comment: `        coffee:

            bin: "C:\\Users\\bhatt_000\\AppData\\Roaming\\coffee.cmd"

            node: "C:\\Ruby193\\node\\node.exe"`  I tried this. It did not work. Same error